# WebRTC: Using own server to counteract quality problems?

Tags: webrtc, video-conferencing

I'm in the process of creating a WebRTC 1-on-1 video chat.

I was told by one of my users that a competitor of mine (who also offers a WebRTC video chat) that if the connections gets bad (=pixelated video and choppy sound), the competitor asks the user if they allow the connection go through their own server instead of p2p.

What might be the reason why they offer users to do it via their own server? Do they use a different system (=not WebRTC?) then?

I thought that nothing could be better than p2p, so I don't understand what my competitors do in such a case where they offer such a workaround.

Thank you for any insights.

Answer (score 0):

Using a server could give you a better experience for a few reasons.

- If you are sending to multiple viewers you have to share your bandwidth between every receiver. When you switch to a server you only have to upload once (and then the server distributes the video to the receivers).
- The network route to the server could be better then the P2P call. If you run your server in something like AWS the two users may have a better network path to the server.
- The server could be doing signal processing on the backend. You have things like SVC and Simulcast, where the sender uploads multiple 'quality levels' to the server, and the server decides which one to distribute.
- Unlikely (but possible) I have seen demos where some companies will use machine learning to improve video. I have never done it myself though!

---

These are all done via WebRTC and common use cases. My guess would be your competitor is using an Open Source SFU/MCU. Many projects exist that cover these use cases.

Comment: I have added the fact that I need only 1-on-1 video chats. Is your answer still valid then, or does it have to be changed? Could you please also explain the AWS more in detail, please? Is it Amazon specific?

Comment: No it is not Amazon specific. It is just usually better having your traffic go through major hosting providers networks then public hops. You should measure though, it could be worse in some cases!

Comment: Thank you. Can you please clarify? Should I use for example "stun.l.google.com" and "turn:numb.viagenie.ca" by default instead of using my own server, and only if the connection gets bad, I should use my own server? Sorry, I didn't get it yet.